# Is Mongoose findOne() as inefficient as MongoDB's findOne()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database-performance

There are a ton of article on MongoDB find() vs findOne() benchmarking. It's well established that find().limit(1) is quite faster than findOne().

I was wondering if the same is true for Mongoose query? I have checked the source code, not that I fully understand it, but seems like it's finally calling the native findOne() of the driver.

In such case why in every example or official code snippets, I'm seeing the use of findOne over the combination of find() and limit().
I'm working on a project where there might be a large number of concurrent requests, so even small performance gain will matter.

Answer (score 1):

> It's well established that find().limit(1) is quite faster than findOne()

It's not, if you actually retrieve that one document from the find query.

See this topic, for example: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7576/3817

Comment: Actually, I just want to check if that id already exists or not. I don't need the document in return, just a binary true or false is sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: @sushobhan: then something like `count()` is more appropriate for this. Out of scope of the question, though.